# a special class for all the data types that I use in a project

Tags: c++, class, typedef

I am using the following data types in my project:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<float>>;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<string>>;
pair<std::vector<string>,double>;
```

These data types are used  repeatedly in many classes of the project. I want to use `typedef`. My question is the following:
Can I create a class especially for data types? For example:

```
class Foo
{
   typedef  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<float>> floatVec;
   typedef  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<string>> stringVec;
   typedef  pair<std::vector<string>,double> pairVec;

};
```

What do you think of this practice?

---

**As a conlusion from what I understood:**

1- typedef shout preferably be used when a class is passed as a template type (Konrad Rudolph)

2- DO NOT ABUSE THE SHARED_PTR (C++ IS NOT JAVA) ok

Comment: I wouldn't put this in a class if I were you, you can just define the types in a separate .h file and include that file everywhere you need the types. If you want to organize them better, use a namespace.

Comment: Why do you have pointers to floats, strings *in the first place*?

Comment: @John Dibling Well because I want to load a file of Float values at Run-time?

Comment: @HaniGoc:  That doesn't justify needing **pointers** to the values.

Comment: Btw, you should put a space between >> at the end of those declarations, it will give trouble with types that overloaded the >> operator like integers.

Comment: @JohnDibling Yes I understand I think that I am abusing the use of pointers even with shared_ptr

Comment: @Kevin That’s wrong. In C++11 it’s the correct (and preferred) syntax for template declarations. Before that, it wouldn’t compile regardless of type. It’s never ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this – as in, it compiles and will work.

But **why** do you want to do this? It seems to have no purpose in this general form. Are you maybe trying to use a class as a namespace?

In general, this screams of lack of thought about the class design. You seem to have only few types without clearly designated purpose, and you’re apparently using (shared) pointers in a completely inappropriate manner.

Comment: do you mean that I should reach this level in my design where I create a class especially for the types?

Comment: The Shared_prt is because I want to load a file of Float values at Run-time?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it’s generally easy and cheap to create a new type for your data, and it makes the code much easier to understand. In general I don’t think it makes sense to put typedefs (or type definitions) into a class unless that class is supposed to be passed around as a template type. The `shared_ptr` part is wrong anyway. Just use values directly.

Comment: OK I understand. How about the Shared_prt? I am abusing their use? Even if it's during run-time?

Answer (score 4):

You should use namespace instead:

```
namespace Foo
```

and the rest the same (just skip the last semicolon). Namespaces are much better suited for such cases as yours.